# Cannot access file from MVC5 class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a class that inherits from DelegatingHandler. In one of the methods of that class I am trying to access a text files like so:

```
string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/test.txt");

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath))
{
    using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(filePath))
    {
        w.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}|{1})", DateTime.Now, ex.ToString()));
    }
}
```

But I keep getting a null error on HttpContext.Current cannot be null

```
string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/test.txt");
```

What could the issue be? I have made sure the file does exist at the site root?

Comment: I think it has something to do with [different threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419033/httpcontext-current-is-null-inside-identity-frameworks-methods).

Comment: Have you given the administrator priviliges to your compiler ?

Answer (score 1):

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/test.txt");
```

- Use this Server.MapPath, it return the current full path of application